# How can I make a table column pre-calculated in mysql?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, field

I'd like to create a table where a column is sum of two other columns like col3 = col1 + col2. I don't want to calculate it in front end:

[image: phpmyadmin screenshot]

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create table in such way but you can achieve this by using view like below.

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS
    SELECT ROLL, PC, PF, PC+PF AS TOTAL, CGPA FROM MY_TABLE;
```

You can access view just like a table.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW;
```

Replace the table and view name with the correct/preferred one.

Comment: Can I use here any function/condition like (if-else)  ?

Comment: You can write any kind of valid SQL statement in crete view.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by using generated columns.